# Spread operator analogue

Tags: go, struct, slice

I have a struct and the instance of that struct:

```
type Obj struct {
  ssid string
  code string
  mit string
  // and other props (23)
}

var ValidObject = Obj {
  ssid: "AK93-KADJ9-92J76",
  code: "SKO-120O"
  mit: "MSLA-923-OKSW"
}
```

I want to create a slice of structs (`Obj`) which will contain `ValidObject` with only some fields changed. I think the best way to explain that would be using pseudo code, so here it is (using spread operator from JS :) ):

```
var slc = []Obj{
  {
    ...ValidObject,
    code: "Other value",
  },
  {
    ...ValidObject,
    mit: "Other value"
  }
}
```

Comment: go does have spread operator but unfortunately it won't work with objects like spread operator in js, you have to create helper function

Answer (score 8):

Create a helper function that takes an `Object`, changes its `code` and returns the new `Object`:

```
func withCode(obj Obj, code string) Obj {
    obj.code = code
    return obj
}
```

Note that `withCode` takes a non-pointer value, so the `Object` you pass will not be modified, only the local copy.

And using this your task is:

```
var slc = []Obj{
    withCode(ValidObject, "Other value"),
    withCode(ValidObject, "Yet another value"),
}
fmt.Println(slc)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/s2hq0qPBFxO)):

```
[{AK93-KADJ9-92J76 Other value MSLA-923-OKSW}
    {AK93-KADJ9-92J76 Yet another value MSLA-923-OKSW}]
```

This helper `withCode` could even be a method (not a function).

Note that if you need to have variations of many fields, it would probably be better to add these as methods, so you can chain the calls.

For example:

```
func (o Obj) withCode(code string) Obj {
    o.code = code
    return o
}

func (o Obj) withSsid(ssid string) Obj {
    o.ssid = ssid
    return o
}

func (o Obj) withMit(mit string) Obj {
    o.mit = mit
    return o
}
```

And then using it:

```
var slc = []Obj{
    ValidObject.withCode("code2").withSsid("ssid2"),
    ValidObject.withMit("mit2").withSsid("ssid3"),
}
fmt.Println(slc)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SL-VXhnHXyp)):

```
[{ssid2 code2 MSLA-923-OKSW} {ssid3 SKO-120O mit2}]
```

Comment: So that means that i need to create a helper function for every field that i want to change?

Comment: @Src You can add more parameters to `withCode()` to change multiple fields (but then you'd probably name it something else).

Comment: The thing is that i need to change only one field at a time.. for each item in slice

Comment: @Src You may create function like: `withCode(obj, paramName, paramValue)` but in this case you have to use reflection and it's slow(

Comment: @Src See edited answer, adding multiple methods, use whichever you want to, and you can even chain them.

Comment: @VladimirKovpak Yeah, i was searching a way to avoid reflection.. i thought that in go we might have similar and more convenient solution  :\

Answer (score -5):

Create a slice of struct `var objCollector = []obj{}` globally and read data into the defined struct and `append` the object into slice of struct that we created.

```
type Obj struct {
    ssid string
    code string
    mit  string
}

var objCollector = []obj{}

func main() {
    var ValidObject = Obj{
        ssid: "AK93-KADJ9-92J76",
        code: "SKO-120O",
        mit:  "MSLA-923-OKSW",
    }
    append(objectCollector, ValidObject)
}
```