# How to make a DTO out of a Swagger generated Golang model

Tags: rest, go, swagger

I have a few problems implementing a REST API in Go.

I use go-swagger to document my API. It generates a model based on structs.

My first problem is I don't know in my swagger yaml file how to define a simple hasMany relationship.

If I need a vehicle that has many wheels. In my database I will have a `vehicle` table and a `wheel` table that contains the `id` of the vehicle.

Since Vehicle has no `wheel_id`, in swagger I get a simple `type: object`.
For wheel I have a property:

```
  vehicle:
    $ref: '#/definitions/Vehicle'
```

This generates a model:

```
type Wheel struct {
  ...
  Vehicle *Vehicle
}
```

Which is not what I want my API to return when I ask for a list of wheels.

So I need a DTO or some kind of mapper to work between the client and the database.

Reading https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/6xgzmp/model_to_dto_mapper_my_first_experience_with_go/
it looks like it's not the way to do things in Go.

Do I need to remove all refs in my swagger file so it better matches the model? (replace $ref with property id: type: string)

Do I need to use reflection as described here: [Spread operator analogue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440765/spread-operator-analogue) ?

What's the best practice in this case?

Comment: It's not clear what you want your web call to accomplish here. If you GET from `/vehicle/{id}`, what do you expect to get back if not a Vehicle? If the `Vehicle` has no concept of its wheels, why do you want a list of its wheels when you hit a `vehicle` endpoint?

Comment: What I want is very standard. I want to customize my responses. If /GET wheel/{id} I don't want the whole vehicle object (that contains lots of other refs)

Comment: Ah then yes, you'll have to create a custom response object, since including a reference to the Vehicle definition is you declaring to Swagger that it should include that model in its return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to make a custom response model in swagger:

```
/vehicle/{id}:
  get:
    ...
    responses:
      '200':
        schema:
          $ref: '#definitions/VehicleCustomeResponse'
```

I think I can use swagger's `anyOf` to reduce the amount of duplication.

Comment: Go-swagger doesn't (and never will) support openAPI 3, so anyOf doesn't help. Models have to be duplicated :(